# In react-router, what is the type of this.context.router?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

To set the context, I am in [lesson 12 of react-router-tutorial](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/blob/start/lessons/12-navigating.md), but as I'm following along, I'm actually doing everything in TypeScript.  At this point in the tutorial, among several React components is one called `Repos`

```
export class Repos extends React.Component<ReposProps, {}> { ... }
```

which is created inside a `Router`

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    {/* ... */}
    <Route path="/repos" component={Repos}>{/* ... */}</Route>
    {/* ... */}
</Router>
```

Somewhere in `Repos` is a method that takes some arguments from an HTML form and constructs a new path to direct the browser to:

```
handleSubmit(event: React.FormEvent) {
    /* ... (define userName and repo vars) */
    const path = `/repos/${userName}/${repo}`
    this.context.router.push(path);
}
```

My question is **what is the type of `context` and `router` on the last line?**

In [the React documentation on Contexts](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) I come to understand that context is generally defined in each element.  It seems like a brilliant idea here would be to define `context` in `Repos` with an interface that extends from some interface defined in [react-router's TypeScript type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/react-router)

```
interface ReposContext extends Something /* ??? */ { }
```

Here, `Something` would have `router` defined as some type that has the `push` method.

The [API](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#router) doesn't say that `Router` has a method `push` although the [Glossary](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/Glossary.md#router) does, which is confusing.  Regardless, the type definitions on DefinitelyTyped do not define a `push` method under `Router` (while I don't believe they are perfect, this omission does not seem accidental to me)

That same API does point out [`RouterContext`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#routercontext) which mentions `context.router` -- `context.router` does define `push()` as well as a number of other methods.

Well then I noticed in history.d.ts in react-router's type definitions, the interface `History` has all the same methods (plus a couple more

Maybe this interface is getting close then.  It's not extending anything as I had wanted it to (maybe this is room for the react-router typings to improve), but it has what I need.

```
interface ContextRouter extends History { }

interface ReposContext {
    router: ContextRouter
}
```

I'm still doubtful because it doesn't quite make sense though that `ContextRouter` extends `History`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this one out by diving into the react-router code.  By figuring out how the router is created, I ended up in [match.js](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/39b36f2af313ce4cd986da4f03d404dc6c5449e6/modules/match.js#L42) where I discovered that the router is in fact created by passing history to createRouterObject which just creates an object with the same properties as the history as well as a couple of other properties.

**The type of router does extend History.**

Answer (score 2):

I use ReactRouter.RouterOnContext:

```
context: {
    router: ReactRouter.RouterOnContext
}
```