# What is the correct way to define a React component's contextTypes in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How does one define the `contextTypes` in TypeScript?

I have a component (*note: I'm unsure of the necessary type of router as detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541455/in-react-router-what-is-the-type-of-this-context-router) but that should be irrelevant here*)

```
export class Repos extends React.Component<ReposProps, {}> {
    context: {
        router: History
    }

    static contextTypes = {
        router: React.PropTypes.object
    };
```

It has a function

```
    public handleSubmit(event: React.FormEvent) {
```

at the end of that function, it calls on context

```
        this.context.router.push(path);
    }
```

The component has a form

```
    public render() {
        return (
            {/* ... */}
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        );
    }
}
```

However, on the line with `this.context.router.push(path);` I receive the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'router' of undefined"  When compiling this same code, I received the TypeScript error in the file that uses Repos in a Router:

```
ERROR in ./index.tsx
(14,34): error TS2322: Type 'typeof Repos' is not assignable to type 'string | ComponentClass<any> | StatelessComponent<
any>'.
  Type 'typeof Repos' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<any>'.
    Types of property 'contextTypes' are incompatible.
      Type '{ router: Requireable<any>; }' is not assignable to type 'ValidationMap<any>'.
```

Changing the contextTypes to

```
static contextTypes: React.ValidationMap<any> = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
};
```

fixed the TypeScript error, although I doubt it was necessary; I suspect a different problem that is the cause of both of these issues.

According to discussions in [TypeScript issue 4785: How to use React contextTypes in Typescript 1.6?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4785), the code above is correct.  If it helps, I'm using TypeScript 1.7.3, React 0.14.7 and react-router 2.0.0.

Comment: If you share the code I can have a look. I personally haven't used `context` or `router` as of yet :)

Comment: [Link to specific commit where things are broken](https://github.com/mjohnsonengr/react-router-typescript-tutorial/tree/744e90c18edffcc36beecdaf87b2dbf47a783401) -- This compiles with TypeScript 1.7.3, but I just noticed 1.8.2 broke it.  Run w/ npm start, navigate to localhost:8080/repos, type in the two text fields and press Go to see the Router undefined error happen.

Comment: I updated that repo with a temp fix for the TS 1.8.2 compile issue.

Comment: Wow I'm an idiot. The problem is binding this.  I don't know if its appropriate to keep this question open or to delete it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've all seen this problem at one time or another in our careers. It's surprising that I didn't catch this.

The problem is that the context of `this` in `handleSubmit()` is different because of how `handleSubmit` is called.  Changing `handleSubmit` into a fat arrow definition works:

```
public handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent) => {
```

In this particular case, I overlooked that because I don't run into this problem often in the TypeScript world (I also don't work with DOM elements often, and have been with React for under a week... *no excuses*, I know)